# JavaScript: Checking if an object field is undefined without checking if the object is undefined

Tags: javascript, types, typeof

My IVR app receives business data in the form of JS objects and arrays.  For example, the name of one of our customers is accessed as follows:

```
customerData.customerList[customerIndex].customerName
```

Now, in some cases, customerName is undefined, because the entire object is undefined.  Right now, in order to catch that, I have some nested logic that checks each level for being undefined, before finally checking the last:

```
if (typeof customerData != 'undefined' &&
  typeof customerData.customerList &&
  typeof customerData.customerList[customerIndex] != 'undefined' &&
  typeof customerData.customerList[customerIndex].customerName != 'undefined')
{
  //do something awesome with customer name, here
}
```

Is there an easier (cleaner?) way to accomplish this, without having to check each field on the object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write the first typeof to ensure that `customerData` has been declared. After that, you can skip testing for undefined upto any level you wish

```
((customerData || {}).customerList || [])[customerIndex] !== undefined
```

Comment: You'll still need a `typeof` check for `customerData` if it hasn't already been declared with `var`.

Comment: You're correct, but after that it's possible to avoid testing for `undefined` upto any level with logical-or

Comment: your approach is clever, it reminds me of an approach I once used when traversing an XML document returned by a web service :-) +1.

Answer (score 1):

I know this works, but would venture to guess there will be some objections... which I'd love to hear:

```
var customerName = function(){
   try{ return customerData.customerList[customerIndex].customerName; }
   catch(e){ return null; }
};
if (customerName) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Try-catch blocks are difficult for browsers to optimize. To learn some more : https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers